# HTML signature resizing and text wrapping in ios

Tags: html, email

I'm fairly new to this and have received some help previously with a different issue on this same code. Once I fix one issue, a new one pops up. The code so far is displaying properly across all email clients except apple mail on iphones [image]

Here is my code. When viewed in ios - it squishes all the left hand side column and wraps text. How can I get it to display the signature at full width across ios?

```html
<br>
<table width="30%" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<style>
a:hover {
    color : #282931;
    text-decoration : none;

a.gold:link, a:visited {
    color : #282931;
    text-decoration : none;
}
a.gold:hover {
    color : #282931;
    text-decoration : none;


}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Spartan:wght@300;700&display=swap');
</style>

  <tr>
     <td bgcolor="#f3f3f1" width="400">
        <p style="font-size:18px;color:#000000;font-family:'Spartan',Century Gothic, sans-serif;;margin-bottom:30px;margin-right: 0px; margin-left:15px; margin-top:30px; font-weight:300;  letter-spacing: 1px;">


            Ben Tindall
            <br>
            <span style="font-size:9px;color:#000000;font-family:'Spartan',Century Gothic, sans-serif; font-weight:300;letter-spacing:0;">

            Managing Director + Licensee            
            </span>
        </p>

        <p style="font-size:9px;color:#000000;font-family:'Spartan',Century Gothic, sans-serif;margin-bottom:20px;   margin-left:15px; margin-top:30px; line-height: 1.5; font-weight:300;">


            179 Darby Street Cooks Hill
            <br />


            NSW 2300
        </p>

      <p style="font-size:9px;color:#000000;font-family:'Spartan',Century Gothic, sans-serif;margin-bottom:15px;   margin-left:15px; margin-top:0px; line-height: 1.5; font-weight:700; white-space: nowrap;">          
          <a href="tel:49295999" style="text-decoration: none;color:#000000">Call the office.</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a href="tel:tel:0419427478" style="text-decoration: none; color: #000000">Call Me.</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="mailto:bentindall@villagerproperty.com.au" style="text-decoration: none;color: #000000;font-size: 9px; white-space: nowrap">Email me.</a>
        </p>
       <p style="font-size:16px;color:#000000;font-family:'Spartan',Century Gothic, sans-serif;margin-bottom:10px;   margin-left:15px; margin-top:0px; line-height: 1.5; font-weight:700;">          




            <a href="https://www.villagerproperty.com.au" style="text-decoration: none;color: #000000;font-size: 16px;color:#000000;font-weight: 700;font-family: 'Spartan',Century Gothic, sans-serif;" class="gold"> 

            villagerproperty.com.au
            </a>
      </p>

      <p style="margin-bottom:0px;  margin-left:15px; margin-top:0px;">

            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/villagerproperty" target="_blank"> 

            <img id="FB" src="https://villagerproperty.com.au/wp-content/uploads/facebook.png" alt="facebook" border="0" align="top"/></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;


            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/villagerproperty/" target="_blank"> 


            <img id="insta" src="https://villagerproperty.com.au/wp-content/uploads/instagram.png" alt="instagram" border="0" align="top"/></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 


            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ben-tindall-a8458799/  " target="_blank"> 


            <img id="li" src="https://villagerproperty.com.au/wp-content/uploads/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin" border="0" align="top"/></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;


            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCKxDK6__4Fka9zj5hZqwOfw" target="_blank"> 


           <img id="yt" src="https://villagerproperty.com.au/wp-content/uploads/youtube.png" alt="youtube" border="0" align="top"/>         
           </a>      
        </p>

    </td>
 <td align="right" valign="top" bgcolor="#f3f3f1">

        <p style="margin-right:0px; margin-top:0px; margin-left: 10px">
             <img src="https://villagerproperty.com.au/wp-content/uploads/BenTindall-e1588743697391.png" alt="" role="presentation">
        </p>

    </td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">
              <p style="font-size: 9px;font-family:'Spartan',Century Gothic, sans-serif;color: #000000; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:15px;">
          This email message is for the exclusive use of the intended recipient(s) and may contain confidential, privileged and non-disclosable information. Any unauthorized review, use, disclosure or distribution is prohibited. If you are not the intended recipient, please contact the sender by reply email immediately and destroy any and all copies of the message.
      </p>  

      <p style="font-size:9px; font-family:'Spartan',Century Gothic, sans-serif; color:#000000; margin-top:10px;">

          Please consider the environment before printing this email. 
      </p>


    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is your question?  "Find the issue" is pretty vague.

Comment: My apologies @jmargolisvt. I've edited my original post.When viewed in ios - it squishes all the left hand side column and wraps text. How can I get it to display the signature at full width across ios?